# Stop function from being invoked multiple times

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, callback, middleware

I'm in the process of building a file upload component that allows you to pause/resume file uploads.

The standard way to achieve this seems to be to break the file into chunks on the client machine, then send the chunks along with book-keeping information up to the server which can store the chunks into a staging directory, then merge them together when it has received all of the chunks. So, this is what I am doing.

I am using node/express and I'm able to get the files fine, but I'm running into an issue because my `merge_chunks` function is being invoked multiple times.

Here's my call stack:

```
router.post('/api/videos', 
    upload.single('file'), 
    validate_params, 
    rename_uploaded_chunk,
    check_completion_status,
    merge_chunks,
    record_upload_date,
    videos.update,
    send_completion_notice
);
```

the `check_completion_status` function is implemented as follows:

```
/* Recursively check to see if we have every chunk of a file */
var check_completion_status = function (req, res, next) {
  var current_chunk = 1;
  var see_if_chunks_exist = function () {
    fs.exists(get_chunk_file_name(current_chunk, req.file_id), function (exists) {
      if (current_chunk > req.total_chunks) { 
        next(); 
      } else if (exists) {
        current_chunk ++;
        see_if_chunks_exist();
      } else { 
        res.sendStatus(202);
      } 
    });
  };
  see_if_chunks_exist();
};
```

The file names in the staging directory have the chunk numbers embedded in them, so the idea is to see if we have a file for every chunk number. The function should only `next()` one time for a given (complete) file.

However, my `merge_chunks` function is being invoked multiple times. (usually between 1 and 4) Logging does reveal that it's only invoked **after** I've received all of the chunks.

With this in mind, my assumption here is that it's the async nature of the `fs.exists` function that's causing the issue.

Even though the `n`'th invocation of `check_completion_status` may occur before I have all of the chunks, by the time we get to the `n`th call to `fs.exists()`, `x` more chunks may have arrived and been processed concurrently, so the function can keep going and in some cases get to the end and `next()`. However those chunks that arrived concurrently are also going to correspond to invocations of `check_completion_status`, which are also going to `next()` because we obviously have all of the files at this point.

This is causing issues because I didn't account for this when I wrote `merge_chunks`.

For completeness, here's the `merge_chunks` function:

```
var merge_chunks = (function () {

  var pipe_chunks = function (args) {
    args.chunk_number = args.chunk_number || 1;
    if (args.chunk_number > args.total_chunks) { 
      args.write_stream.end();
      args.next(); 
    } else {
      var file_name = get_chunk_file_name(args.chunk_number, args.file_id)
      var read_stream = fs.createReadStream(file_name);
      read_stream.pipe(args.write_stream, {end: false});
      read_stream.on('end', function () {
        //once we're done with the chunk we can delete it and move on to the next one.
        fs.unlink(file_name);
        args.chunk_number += 1;
        pipe_chunks(args);
      }); 
    }  
  };

  return function (req, res, next) {
    var out = path.resolve('videos', req.video_id);
    var write_stream = fs.createWriteStream(out);
    pipe_chunks({
      write_stream: write_stream,
      file_id: req.file_id,
      total_chunks: req.total_chunks,
      next: next
    });
  };

}());
```

Currently, I'm receiving an error because the second invocation of the function is trying to read the chunks that have already been deleted by the first invocation.

What is the typical pattern for handling this type of situation? I'd like to avoid a stateful architecture if possible. Is it possible to cancel pending handlers right before calling `next()` in check_completion_status?

Comment: `check_completion_status` looks fine to me. The only way `merge_chunk` can be called multiple times, is if the `next()` in `check_completion_status` is fired multiple times, and I don't see how that would happen. Are you positive then `check_completion_status` isn't being fired multiple times? Presumably by previous middleware.

Comment: @YuriZarubin This is the only route that uses that function. I put a `console.log()` at the beginning of  `merge_chunks`and it's only fired *after* I've received all of the chunks, (and there's no extraneous requests coming in in between).  What flaws do you see in my current theory?

Comment: I think I'm missing something, what is your theory as to why `merge_chunk` is firing multiple times? As I see it, it should be executed ONCE when `current_chunk > req.total_chunks`. Is this not the case?

Comment: @YuriZarubin For any given call to `check_completion_status`, `next()` will only be called once, but I think that since it takes time to recursively check the existence of all of those files, by the time the n'th invocation of `check_completion_status` gets that far into execution, `x` more chunks may have arrived and been handled concurrently, so I end up with next being called multiple times in the end.

Comment: @YuriZarubin I'm going to try to edit the question to make this more clear.

Comment: @YuriZarubin See my edits.

Comment: Is `'/api/videos'` being called by the client multiple times? Once per chunk?

Comment: @YuriZarubin Yes, exactly.

Comment: Oh ok, then yeah, what you're doing isn't going to work. Even though you once said that you don't want to make your server stateful, your implementation is doing just that (each request put the server into a certain state). So you might as well implement some sort of in-memory store (probably a queue) and push chunk ids into it, and write the appropriate consumption logic. This of course wont scale past a single process (but neither will your current logic). You also won't need to poll `fs.exists` which could potentially result in a infinite loop if one of the requests fails.

Comment: @YuriZarubin I really appreciate your time here, Yuri. Thank you. Could you possibly provide an example in an answer and maybe an elaboration on some of those points? This is actually my first real node project :/

Comment: @YuriZarubin I actually thought of a different approach. What If, when the server realizes it has all of the chunks, instead of immediately merging, it sends back a "ready to merge" message to the client. It would then be up to the client to send a request to a different route specifically for merging the files. The client would be responsible for tracking the state and it should expect to get multiple "ready to merge" responses, but only handle one. What do you think of this as opposed to using an in-memory queue? (It's more network requests, but is it maybe worth it?)

Comment: That would work. It totally depends on the type of application you're trying to create. If you're just trying to get it to work by any means, I'd use a simple lock. See my answer for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to make it work ASAP, I would use a lock (much like a db lock) to lock the resource so that only one of the requests processes the chunks. Simply create a unique id on the client, and send it along with the chunks. Then just store that unique id in some sort of a data structure, and look that id up prior to processing. The example below is by far not optimal (in fact this map will keep growing, which is bad), but it should demonstrate the concept

```
// Create a map (an array would work too) and keep track of the video ids that were processed. This map will persist through each request.
var processedVideos = {};

var check_completion_status = function (req, res, next) {
  var current_chunk = 1;
  var see_if_chunks_exist = function () {
    fs.exists(get_chunk_file_name(current_chunk, req.file_id), function (exists) {
      if (processedVideos[req.query.uniqueVideoId]){
        res.sendStatus(202);
      } else if (current_chunk > req.total_chunks) { 
        processedVideos[req.query.uniqueVideoId] = true;
        next(); 
      } else if (exists) {
        current_chunk ++;
        see_if_chunks_exist();
      } else { 
        res.sendStatus(202);
      } 
    });
  };
  see_if_chunks_exist();
};
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I may end up creating a separate question focused on improving the code to be more scale-able